# Php - CSS elements wont load

Tags: php, html, css

I am new to this board and since I sadly couldn't find the answer while searching for it, I thought I should post it here :P

Enough from me, I've got the following problem:

I made a website (for practice) and tried to make a guestbook in it.
Worked out pretty well so far, yet I have one big problem. As soon as I try to get from one .php page to another .php page and include a HTML page on there, it wont load the CSS elements anymore.

When going from a .html page to a .php page and including a HTML page, it works perfectly fine.

I've also checked if the path are correct, and if this bug appears on more than just that one .php page, and yea, it made always problems in that scenario.

Here are the `include` and stylesheet I am using (I hope that's all you need as information)

```
include('gaestebuchAfterLogin.html');
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../../css/style.css" type="text/css">
```

Edit:
here is some more code:

```
<?php
session_start();
?>

<?php 

if(isset($_SESSION["login"])) 
   { 
        include('gaestebuchAfterLogin.html');
   }
else
{
    include('gaestebuchFail.html');
}
?> 

<?php 
session_start(); 
?>
```

^ one PHP Element

```
<?php 
if(!isset($_SESSION["username"])) 
   { 
   echo "Bitte erst <a href=\"login.html\">einloggen</a>"; 
   exit; 
   } 
?>
```

^ the second PHP Element (for example)
well, as said, the include works perfectly fine, when i haven't been on a .php page before. But if i have been on a php page before, it wont work anymore

Edit2:
sorry for posting in answers and thanks for the quick responses :P
Anyways, tried to use the absolute path now, did not work out, too

Comment: Show a bit more code around what you gave us, specifically where is the `<?php` and `>?`

Comment: Try calling that css in the master/parent page

Comment: Have you "viewed source" (ctrl-u on most browsers) to see if the css file is actually registered on the page?

Comment: Also check in the developer tools (F12) in the network tab to see if it is actually loaded. Maybe the path is incorrect.

Comment: Can you show us the entire file or a link to the source code?

Comment: Try using and Absolute Path instead of a Relative Path.  I think it will show you where you are going wrong.

Comment: Why `session_start();` TWICE. Why keep starting and stopping the PHP interpreter for no reason

Comment: Where is the `<link rel="stylesheet" href="../../css/style.css" type="text/css">` in the code you added???

Answer (score 0):

try and use absolute paths instead, change:

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="../../css/style.css" type="text/css">`

into:

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style.css" type="text/css">`

Comment: Your "into" does not seem to be absolute path.

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/style.css" type="text/css">
```

Or create a path variable from root using $_SERVER to get your url.
Define it and then include your php in the page.

```
$app_url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_SCHEME'].'://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']).'/';
```

define("APP_URL",$app_url);

and then

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo APP_URL?>css/style.css" type="text/css">
```